# How to use the Flutter AAR file in android native application

Tags: android

I have created a flutter application, now I want to covert this application as an.AAR, I will call this.AAR file in another Native android application. I followed this URL :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps.
By using the above URL am able to generate the .AAR file,how can i call the native application to Flutter .AAR file?.In the Settings.gradle file we need to add the these lines of code

```
// MyApp/settings.gradle
include ':app'                                     // assumed existing content
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))                                 // new
evaluate(new File(                                                      // new
  settingsDir.parentFile,                                               // new
  'my_flutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'                          // new
))
```

Here I don't have the include_flutter. groovy file because I have only AAR file.
 I need to give.AAR file to my client, not the total code.
Please give any examples or solutions
Thanks in advance.

Comment: AAR files are intended for DEVELOPMENT usage before and/or during the build procedure. AAR files contains Code and Resources that should be prepared to be read by the Runtime. It's not possibile to load an AAR file in runtime directly. You have to do some work on this AAR: https://medium.com/@artyomdangizyan/aar-to-dex-loading-and-running-code-at-runtime-in-android-application-69089a30c715

Comment: @Avinash Kumar hello , i have the same problem , could you use aar file from flutter project in android or ios native projects?
please let me know if you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

You should compile fat-aar file via special plugin, for instance https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android.

I've wrote an article about building aar from existing Flutter project, but it's in russian language https://medium.com/@askarsyzdykov/android-lib-with-flutter-module-a124ffcd758?source=friends_link&sk=750a1293b2a890cb5725841dad3758a6. Soon I'll translate the article into English.

Additionally see my repo https://github.com/askarsyzdykov/native_flutter_lib